# Can we convert OWL or RDF file into First Order Logic (FOL)?

Tags: rdf, owl, first-order-logic

I would be very pleased to know, are there any means available to convert RDF or OWL into First-Order Logic (FOL) format?

Thanking in advance

Kind Regards

Comment: some Java code in a Bachelor thesis: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.458.3145&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Thank you very much AKSW for your kind support.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you tell us why do you need to translate OWL into FOL? What do you intend to do with the resulting set of First Order Formulas. Without details like this a question is more of a theoretical nature and unless a short "Yes" is not the answer you are looking for, this post would be better suited for [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2):

Hets can translate OWL into FOL, see the [Hets homepage](http://hets.eu) and the [online interface](http://rest.hets.eu)
If you have locally installed Hets (or Hets-server, or the corresponding [docker container](https://github.com/spechub/Hets/wiki/How-to-use-the-Hets-Docker-Container)), you can e.g. translate an OWL file (any syntax) to FOL in [TPTP syntax](http://www.tptp.org/) by

```
hets -t OWL22CASL:CASL2TPTP_FOF -o tptp -v2 my_ontology.owl
```

With

```
hets -t OWL22CASL -o casl -v2 my_ontology.owl
```

you get the more readable but a bit less familiar [CASL syntax](http://www.cofi.info).